# SQL Server trigger: how to increase column's value in table when another table's column value increased?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Table component:

[image]

Table material:

[image]

How can I write a trigger to decrease the `material_quantity` value in the `material` table when `component_quantity` is increased?

By the way the component is made from material so when one component's quantity is increased, the material's quantity which has same `material_id` will be decrease with the same amount.

Comment: Simply issue an UPDATE command.

Answer (score 2):

After insert/update trigger should help you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_name
ON dbo.components
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE m
    SET material_quantity = m.material_quantity - (i.component_quantity - c.component_quantity)
    FROM materials m
    INNER JOIN components c ON c.material_id = m.material_id
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON c.component_id = i.component_id
END
```

Comment: When an `UPDATE` occurs your code doesn't take into account any values in `deleted`, i.e calculate the deltas resulting from the update. I wonder what the OP might want.

Comment: @HABO yes, thought of it too. But better use another trigger on delete. And there should be foreign key so the deletion might not go well